# Как вывести x элемент y раз в postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, функции

Всем привет.

Подскажите плиз:есть таблица вида

```
-------------
|id|duration|
```

Как посредством postgresql вывести значение (допустим 1 ), столько раз , сколько содержит значение duration.
Например , если duration имеет значение 4, то вывести 1111
И сделать это для всех элементов таблицы , (id 1-100, допустим).

Answer (score 2):

> Например , если duration имеет значение 4, то вывести 1111

Это одна запись, одно поле, и в нём 4 единицы? тогда

```
SELECT REPEAT(id::text, duration)
FROM source_table
```

Если же это 4 записи, и у каждой в поле одна единица, то

```
SELECT id
FROM source_table
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, (SELECT MAX(duration)
                               FROM source_table))
WHERE generate_series <= duration
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение       :)

Answer (score 0):

Если id не более одного знака - то делаем просто:

```
select lpad('', t.duration, cast(t.id as varchar(1))) from t
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/df3d7/3

`lpad` дополняет слева строку из первого параметра до длины из второго параметра символом из третьего параметра.
Можно также использовать и `rpad`, поскольку у нас пустая строка

Если id больше 1 знака - нужно будет посчитать длину конечной строки:

```
select lpad('', t.duration*length(cast(t.id as varchar)), cast(t.id as varchar)) from t
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/af622/8

Comment: Ну зачем же так сложно-то...

Comment: Спасибо за решение       :)